# How can I get a Uint8List image size?

Tags: flutter, dart, size, uint8list

I want to find out the size of an `Uint8List` image before I upload it to firebase storage using

```
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putData(uint8ListImage);
```

wherein `uint8ListImage` is a `Uint8List`. Is there a way to find out the size of the `Uint8List`?

Comment: Size in bytes or in pixels? If you just need the size in bytes... then you just need `uint8ListImage.length`

Comment: yeah, I need just size in bytes. Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this,

`print(uint8ListImage.lengthInBytes);`

this will print the size in bytes